# How i can perform Token based Authentication in SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, access-token

I am using signalR in asp.net mvc application,I want to authenticate cross
domain clients by token based authentication.I did not found complete solution for
it.

```
 app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        map.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider()
        });

        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            Resolver = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver,
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });

    public class QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
        {
            var value = context.Request.Query.Get("access_token");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                context.Token = value;
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }

    public class impAuthHub : Hub
    {
        [Authorize]
        public void SendMessage(string name, string message)
        {
           Clients.All.newMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

I dont know how i will get token to pass query string to my startup class?

Comment: But I am working on Asp.net Mvc.

Answer (score 1):

You will be needed to use OAuth Bearer Token authentication with SignalR. and you need to use Microsoft’s OWIN Security and ASP.NET Identity libraries then include the WebAPI and Individual Accounts security options. This is a [Full- Demo](https://blog.marcinbudny.com/2014/05/authentication-with-signalr-and-oauth.html#.VlPD5f6wqM8)

Please  find the code base for working sample [git](https://github.com/marcinbudny/SignalRBearerTokenSample) , which will help you.

Comment: If I interpret this codebase correctly, it assumes the SignalR server will act as the authorization server, but what if this reponsibility is handled by a third party identity provider? (IdentityServer, Keycloak, whatever)

Comment: To answer my own question, following addition in Startup is sufficient: 
```map.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication```, with a Provider in which we set the token on the ```OAuthRequestTokenContext```. In the Hub class we can then just use the standard ```Authorize``` attribute.